# How to get the address (street, house, etc.) when you click on a map in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

It is necessary that when you click on the map, the address (street, house, etc.) is displayed. Now when you click, I have latitude and longitude.

How to implement this? Send request with latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reverse geocoding from https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/ or https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.

Example using openstreetmap api:

```
const reverseGeocoding = await axios.get(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&format=jsonv2`,);

const { city, postcode, road, suburb, town } = reverseGeocoding.data.address;

const displayLocation = `${road}, ${suburb ? `${suburb},` : ''}${postcode}, ${city || town}`,
```